# Are queries called parallel or in sequence?

Tags: mysql

Given this table:

```
id | field
----------
 1 |   2
```

Would it be possible that  the column `field` is only incremented once, if two processes run in parallel this query:

> UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE id = 1

In other words, if the above query would be executed twice, would it be possible to end up with the following database?

```
id | field
----------
 1 |   3
```

I searched at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html but I was not able to find an answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `autocommit = ON`, the two queries will run one after the other.

With

```
BEGIN;
some stuff
that UPDATE 
more stuff
ROLLBACK; -- either explicitly, or because of some error
```

the `UPDATE` will be undone.

Check for errors after *every* query.

(If this does not suffice, please provide more info.)